# how can i hide fragment via a button located inside the same fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

i'm calling fragment via button within the main activity with this (i'm using bundle to send data here)

```
String ScoreText ; 
Scooore myFragment = new Scooore();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("score", scoreText);
myFragment.setArguments(data);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.showScore, myFragment).commit();
```

then inside my score fragment i have button there , and i wanna know what code shall i put inside the onClicklistener method there so that button wpild take me back to the main activity

i can use new intent and go back there or even hide the frame layout using setVisibility on it
, but ig maybe there's better options, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity, add transaction to back stack:

---

```
fragmentTransaction.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("scoore");
```

---

and then in your fragment pop it from the back stack:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

---